# How to statically type an object's keys but dynamically the object's values?

Tags: typescript

I want to create an object whose keys are from a string union type and whose values are functions. The tricky bit is that I want the function typings to come from the implementation of each function, rather than a statically defined type.

Without explicitly typing the object, all the functions are correctly typed, but there is no way to enforce that that all the keys are accounted for.

```
type MyFunctionKeys = 'func1' | 'func2'

const MyFunctions = {
  func1: (num: number) => num + 1,
  // func2 is missing, but no error is thrown
}

MyFunctions.func1(3)
MyFunctions.func1('3') // This should and DOES error: "string not assignable to number"
```

But once you enforce the keys of the object, how do you still dynamically type the functions?

```
type MyFunctionKeys = 'func1' | 'func2'
type MyFunctionValues = Function // <-- WHAT TO PUT HERE??

// This should error and DOES: "Property 'func2' is missing in type"
const MyFunctions: Record<MyFunctionKeys, MyFunctionValues> = {
  func1: (num: number) => num + 1,
  // func2: (str: string) => str + '1',
}

// This should throw an error but DOESN'T
MyFunctions.func1('3')
```

It seems like the typescript [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) keyword might be called for here, but I don't know how to make it work in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combination of a mapped type and the `satisfies` operation:

```
type MyFunctionKeys = 'func1' | 'func2'

type MyCollection = {
  [key in MyFunctionKeys]: Function;
}

// This should error and DOES: "Property 'func2' is missing in type"
const MyFunctions1 = {
  func1: (num: number) => num + 1,
} satisfies MyCollection;

// This should throw an error and DOES!
MyFunctions1.func1('3')

// Valid
const MyFunctions2 = {
  func1: (num: number) => num + 1,
  func2: () => "hi"
} satisfies MyCollection;

// Valid
MyFunctions2.func1(3)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbINIRAGcoBeKAcgDMVUBGcqAHwurQCZyAoT0SWEAMJYANsIjpsyUlADenKFADaAawJQMUuEjSYc+IgF0AXFG0ScAbk4BfbgHo7UACoALDMUIusiYQBMoEABOgViBUACGyP4AIgDyAKIAyiYARAAKIZCBoCw0HOrEALbuhBoA5upSvBApnKg4hMD8ZrrIhLTScgqsdCYAFMiIhSaDhQBGQQCUpAB8UKNQANRQtAA0NlCE4ZiElBgQxHBCouKtVpwOzm4eXj7+wC4hAO4RUkEhYZExCYkAhJxaGitdoAOh6tD65AAzORJvZHAA1cLCDC+OoNJqAnSSQhsTryKDg-qjEZDCaBaYkOYLZZrAk9Nj9SlzFJuWrWTbbdx7A78Y5iczIc6XJEotFYwW4sE0CFQuFAA)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

- `(...args: any) => any` to allow only functions as values
- `satisfies` to keep the signatures of function in you object literal (and not tu narrow them down to generic function)

```ts
type MyFunctionKeys = 'func1' | 'func2'
type MyFunctionValues = (...args: any) => any

const myFunctions = {
  func1: (num: number) => num + 1,
  func2: (str: string) => str + '1',
} satisfies Record<MyFunctionKeys, MyFunctionValues>; // OK

const myFunctionsERROR = {
  func1: (num: number) => num + 1,
} satisfies Record<MyFunctionKeys, MyFunctionValues>; // missing Func2

myFunctions.func1('3'); //Expected error
```